# Map indexed by tuples in VC++

Tags: visual-c++, c++11, tuples

Consider the following code:

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename Map, typename K>
void mymapfunc(Map& m, const K& key) 
{
    m[key] = 1;
}

void f() 
{
    typedef std::tuple<int,int> Pair;
    std::map<Pair,int> m;
    mymapfunc(m, Pair(1,2));
}
```

This code fails in VC++ 2010, but compiles fine in gcc 4.5 (without warnings with -Wall and -pedantic). The error is somewhere inside `<tuple>` and hard to decipher.

If `std::tuple` is changed to `std::pair`, everything works. What is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is [a bug in Visual C++ 2010](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/534457/c-map-tuple-v-compilation-problems) when using a `std::tuple` as a key type in an associative container (like `std::map`).

The workaround (mentioned in the linked bug report) is to construct a temporary `std::tuple`:

```
m[K(key)] = 1;
```

Comment: Bah! It was discovered about a year ago and still not fixed. Thank you for your answer, though.

Answer (score 1):

[N3242](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf), 20.4.2.7 [tuple.rel] defines the relational operators for tuple.

If you add `#include <map>`, this example also compiles fine in [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/).